# Converting Oracle's join syntax using the plus sign (+) to standard join syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am trying to understand Oracle join syntax of using (+) to join two tables. 
Could someon show me how would this query would look if it was converted to use the standard join syntax?

```
select p1.product_id, p1.product_name, p2.product_code, (decode(p3.product_type, null, 'N/A',p3.product_type) as product_type
from products p1, product_descriptions p2, product_descriptions p3
where p1.product_id=p2.product_id
and p2.product_age=p3.product_age(+)
and p2.product_type=p3.product_type(+)
and p3.status(+)='VALID'
```

Comment: You're missing a table with prefix p4 in this query....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select p1.product_id, p1.product_name, p2.product_code,
    (decode(p3.product_type, null, 'N/A', p3.product_type) as product_type
from products p1
join product_descriptions p2
    on p1.product_id = p2.product_id
left join product_descriptions p3
    on p3.product_age = p2.product_age
    and p3.product_type = p2.product_type
    and p3.status = 'VALID';
```

The `where p1.product_id=p2.product_id` is a normal inner join between `p1` and `p2`. The others are outer joins; the way it's written looks like a mix of left and right outer joins, but since `and p2.product_age=p3.product_age(+)` is the same as `and p3.product_age(+)=p2.product_age` then it isn't really; it's a fairly straightforward left outer join between the product of the `p1`/`p2` join and `p3`.

As an aside, I'm not a fan of aliases like `p1`, `p2` and `p3` as they are not descriptive, and it's easy to get lost when you do this in more complicated queries. [I'm not alone](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

I'm not sure you even need the outer join, but it rather depends on the data. If `product_age` and `product_type` is unique then you could `case` the `p2.status`; if it isn't then you're probably assuming that only one `product_age`/`product_type` row can be `VALID`, otherwise you'd get duplicates. Just musing about what you're trying to do...

Comment: interesting.. i was expecting one normal join + two right outer joins and one left outer join

Comment: @ziggy - I think/hope that's right and reversing the order of the terms in the `and` clauses switches it... it's been a while since I used the `(+)` syntax. It can only be one outer join though, you wouldn't have multiple join clauses between the two table instances. You've got three conditions for the same join, not three separate joins.